# MYSQL query not working as wanted

Tags: mysql, select, count, inner-join, relation

I want to be able to get the pieces evidence within a trybe. But I have to go through the ambition table which is the relation from trybe to evidence.

So basically get count(e.id) from

The query i have at the moment is as follows:

```
$evidence = array(1,2,10,20,40,60,80,100,200,300,400,500,1000,1500,2000);
$evidence = implode(", ", $evidence);

# no of evidence in trybe = the x trybe now has over x evidence

$query = sprintf("SELECT t.id, t.name, COUNT(e.id) as number, 'trybe_evidence' AS type
        FROM x_trybes t
        INNER JOIN x_ambition_owner ao ON (t.id = ao.trybe_id)
            LEFT JOIN x_evidence e ON (ao.id = e.ambition_id)
        GROUP BY t.id, t.name
            HAVING COUNT(e.id) in (%s)",$evidence);
```

How can I get all the pieces of evidence from all the ambitions within the trybe table?

The structure of the tables are as follows:

**x_trybes**

```
id  name
```

**x_ambition_owner**

```
id  ambition_id trybe_id
```

**x_ambition** - ambition info

```
id      name      etc.
```

**x_evidence**

```
id  ambition_id name
```

Please note there can be many trybes, many ambitions and many pieces of evidence.

Thanks

Comment: What is `%s`?  It doesn't seem needed in your query.

Comment: It is a set of values, i.e. so that the query only returns the row if the count is equal to a set value. I.e. an array that I can edit, e.g. 10,20,30,40

Comment: From a glance, your query looks ok. I would double check whether your `%s` is correct or not.

Comment: Yeah it is correct, i'll update question now, with the sprintf

Comment: added sprintf, please have a look :)

Comment: What does your query have to do with your question : `How can I get all the pieces of evidence from all the ambitions within the trybe table?`. Your query counts the number of related x-evidence. Are you asking how to list the x_evidence.name column also within that query? Can you show a result set that you want?

Comment: I'm trying to get all pieces of evidence within a trybe that has the exact values given in the $evidence array. The output hopefully will be: THE STACKOVERFLOW TRYBE HAS SURPASSED 300 PIECES OF EVIDENCE. Get where I'm coming from? But i've got to go through the ambitions table to retrieve the pieces of evidence